# Why my svg is not centered inside div container?

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I have the following code

```css
.services-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.services-container svg {
    width: 70px;
  /*margin: 0 auto;
    display: block; */

}

.services-branding {
    width: 300px;
}

.services-branding figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}

.services-branding p {
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
  <div class="services-container">
        <figure class="services-branding">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width="120"
            height="124"
            viewBox="0 0 120 124"
          >
            <g>
              <g>
                <g><path fill="#d84848" d="M120 14H56v66h64L99.844 47z" /></g>
                <g><path fill="#aa1f1f" d="M56 66.75V80l17-11z" /></g>
                <g><path fill="#f57b71" d="M73 69H25L6.656 5H73z" /></g>
                <g>
                  <path
                    fill="#daeaf2"
                    d="M4.436.18a5 5 0 0 1 6.123 3.536l30.54 113.98a5 5 0 0 1-9.658 2.587L.9 6.304A5 5 0 0 1 4.435.18z"
                  />
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <figcaption>branding</figcaption>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
            nonummy nibh.
          </p>
        </figure>
      </div>
```

My question is why the svg is not centered like others elements?
It only works when I add to svg display:block and margin: 0 auto but
Im not sure if this the right way to center it.
Could you guys explain me?
Thanks from in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its because `text-align: center` would not center the `<svg>`. You need to apply the `flexbox` properties to the direct parent of the `<svg>`, which is `.services-branding` like shown below:

```css
.services-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.services-container svg {
  width: 70px;
}

.services-branding {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.services-branding figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}

.services-branding p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="services-container">
  <figure class="services-branding">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="124" viewBox="0 0 120 124">
      <g>
        <g>
          <g><path fill="#d84848" d="M120 14H56v66h64L99.844 47z" /></g>
          <g><path fill="#aa1f1f" d="M56 66.75V80l17-11z" /></g>
          <g><path fill="#f57b71" d="M73 69H25L6.656 5H73z" /></g>
          <g>
            <path
              fill="#daeaf2"
              d="M4.436.18a5 5 0 0 1 6.123 3.536l30.54 113.98a5 5 0 0 1-9.658 2.587L.9 6.304A5 5 0 0 1 4.435.18z"
            />
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <figcaption>branding</figcaption>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh.
    </p>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, but I think it can be minimized to a parent `div` with style `display:flex; justify-content: center;` and containing the `svg`.

Comment: I dont understand why having `style="text-align:center"` on the parent `<div>` won't work, because it works in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56101281/698168

Answer (score 5):

It's a property of SVG elements, their node points (viewport and viewbox) are by standard, starting on the top-left and not on the center of the SVG element. So that's why whenever you try to center the vector, it doesn't fit right like images.

You could try to add :

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

OR, add `text-align: center;` to the container `<div>`

Also, you could check out trying to add `preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet"` to the `<svg>` tag

I'd recommend you to have different sizes of the vector as images and use them accordingly on your needs while builing the code of your page, as it's easier to manipulate images rather than vectors on CSS.

More information about vectors : https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp

And about the preserveAspectRatio : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: I tested the three methods. Having `style="display:block; margin:auto"` on the `<svg>` works. Having `style="text-align:center"` on the parent `<div>` works. But preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet"`` on the `<svg>` tag does not work (nor variants such as `xMidYMid`). But that's not an issue as the two other methods works.